# Get info (document.getElementById) from an iFrame

Tags: javascript

I am getting the value "msg" from the page `http://www.kimi007.freeiz.com/frame.html` with the following code (address must be in the address bar and then you hit 'enter', thus getting the alert message "success!"):

```
javascript:
(function()
   {
      var%20s=document.createElement("script");
      s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
      s.setAttribute("src","http://www.kimi007.freeiz.com/java.js");
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
   }
)()
```

The above has these two lines in the .js file:

```
var capForm = document.getElementById('form').elements[0].value;
alert('' + capForm + '');
```

I have no problems up to this stage. However I want to put "frame.html" in an iFrame like this:

```
http://www.kimi007.freeiz.com/test.html
```

and have my Java code work so I can get the same "success!" message from within the iFrame. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code, might do the trick:

```
top.frames[name_of_the_frame].some_function()
```